# Toggle groundoverlay in google maps with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We have a google maps V3 map. With a ground overlay in a function. We have a menu with items and i want when clicked on a link the groundoverlay appear and when click again, dissapear.

This is my code so far but it doesn't work yet.

Any tips ?

```
function Radarlaag() {
radarOverlay.setMap(null);
radarOverlay.setMap(map);
}
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
<li><a href="#" class="icon radar" id="radar_box" onclick="Radarlaag();">Radar</a></li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What works and what doesn't?

Comment: Thanks, the groundoverlay works, but there is some problem with the function / toggle link to let the groundoverlay display or hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link calls the `Radarlaag` function which does:

`radarOverlay.setMap(null);` - Removes the overlay
`radarOverlay.setMap(map);` - Adds the overlay

With the [getMap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GroundOverlay) method you should be able to do something like:

```
function Radarlaag() {

    if (radarOverlay.getMap()) {

        radarOverlay.setMap(null);

    } else {

        radarOverlay.setMap(map);
    }
}
```

This is untested.

**Edit:** you are also calling `Radarlaag` in the `setTimeout` function so that will just turn it on and off every sec. I don't know if this is an attempt to refresh the GIF file?

Comment: THanks, but still get message: Uncaught ReferenceError: radarLaag is not defined

Comment: When do you get that message? Did you remove/comment the setTimeout function?

Comment: Problem is when i click on the link. Chrome javascript console show me this error!

Comment: Remove the onclick from the link and add this to your script: `document.getElementById('radar_box').addEventListener("click", Radarlaag);`

Comment: In or out the function ?

Comment: In the document ready function if you have one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the